# What is the best way to create a helper which collect a set of data in React app

Tags: javascript

I created this helper in my React app to map over some data:

```
import * as Icon from 'app/components/atoms/icons';

const MyMapping = {
  'Map one': { Icon: Icon.ThemeOneIcon, Color: #66765, BG },
  'Mao two': { Icon: Icon.ThemeTwoIcon, Color: #66765, BG },
};

export default MyMapping;
```

I used it for the icon that's working fine. Now I need to greb the key string `Map one` for a specific case:

```
  let themeIcon: React.FC<React.SVGProps<SVGSVGElement>>;
  let themeTitle: string;

  switch (activeTheme) {
    case 'theme_one':
      themeIcon = MyMapping['Map one'].Icon;
      themeTitle = `This title belongs to `{// How do I return the correct key string here: Map one ?}`;
      break;
    default:
  }
```

Is this a good way to collect the data in a helper or can I refactor and improve this?

Comment: How do you get the value ` MyMapping['Map one']` in the first place? Isn't this already the string you are searching for?

Comment: @Kilian no that returns ` [object Object]`

Comment: that is not what I meat. In the above case you already access the property a line before using they key. can't you just use this value? If you just pass the returned object around why would you need to have the key in the first place? In that case add a new property to the object called title.

Answer (score 0):

Why not convert your Map to an array and select the index you want?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).